# Draw a rectangle with two points in wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

How can I draw a rectangle using two sets of points, lets say 
(X1=10, Y1=20) and (X2=100, Y2=200), using the dc.DrawRectangle() method. It only takes one set of points but I need it to draw the rectangle using two sets of points?

Comment: `dc.DrawRectangle()` takes 2 points...

Comment: Oh sorry i meant 2 sets of co-ordinates, will edit the question soon

Comment: are you looking for `dc.DrawRectangle(10, 20, 100, 200);`?

Comment: yes but wouldn't the last two points 100 and 200 just be the sizes of the rectangle then?

Comment: `dc.DrawRectangle(10, 20, 100 - 10, 200 - 20)`?

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong but isn't the parameters for dc.DrawRectanglelike this-->>dc.DrawRectangle(x point, y point, width, height)

Comment: I need it to take two X and Y points

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15257/discussion-between-user1401950-and-irrelephant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pt1 = (10, 20)
pt2 = (100, 200)
# calculate top left corner coords, width, height
min_x = min(pt1[0], pt2[0]) # left
min_y = min(pt1[1], pt2[1]) # top
width = max(pt1[0], pt2[0])-min_x
height = max(pt1[1], pt2[1])-min_y
# draw rectangle 
dc.DrawRectangle(min_x, min_y, width, height)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that (X1, Y1) is the upper left, and (X2, Y2) is the lower right, then you can use:

```
dc.DrawRectangle(X1, Y1, X2-X1, Y2-Y1)
```

More generally,

```
dc.DrawRectangle(min(X1,X2), min(Y1,Y2), abs(X1-X2), abs(Y1-Y2))
```

should always work (at least for rectangles that are aligned with the x and y axes).